# Activity Does not show up when Alarm Raised

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

i've schedule an alarm to start an Broadcast Reciver when it's time raised and and inside the broadcast check's for some param of alarm object to determine which activity to start .. the app works find when the screen is on but when screen is locked it's not working

Here's what i did :

-this for schedule the alarm

```
/*  Prepare Alarm Intent*/
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ctx, LockRoute.class);
            alarmIntent.putExtra(CONSTANTS.ALARM_NAME, alarm.alarmName);
            alarmIntent.putExtra(CONSTANTS.ALARM_TONE, alarm.tone);
            alarmIntent.putExtra(CONSTANTS.ALARM_LOCK_TYPE, alarm.unLockType);


            //prepare the Pending intent

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, day.getId().intValue(), alarmIntent, 0);
```

and this is the broadcast

```
 /* Pass Alarm Info to unLock Screen*/
        alarmRaised.putExtra(CONSTANTS.ALARM_NAME,bundle.getString(CONSTANTS.ALARM_NAME));
        alarmRaised.putExtra(CONSTANTS.ALARM_TONE,bundle.getString(CONSTANTS.ALARM_TONE));
        alarmRaised.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(alarmRaised);
```

And i added the flags for activity to show up when device is locked

```
 pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        Logger.init();
         /* Check Device SDK to call the correct Function to TURN ON SCREEN */
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 20) {
            if (!pm.isScreenOn()) {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                        +WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                        +WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
                Logger.d("less than 20");
            }else {
                Logger.d("SCREEN ON < 20");
            }

        } else {
            if (!pm.isInteractive()) {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                        +WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                        +WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
                Logger.d("bigger = than 20");
            }else {
                Logger.d("SCREEN ON else 20");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made an application which schedules an Alarm which rings no matter whether the screen is locked or not. This may help you with you AlarmReciever.class file.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {


    //this will sound the alarm tone
    //this will sound the alarm once, if you wish to
    //raise alarm in loop continuously then use MediaPlayer and setLooping(true)
    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null) {
        alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();

    //this will send a notification message
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            AlarmService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

}

and to call this you will be needing to edit in the AlarmActivity.class file

```
final Intent my_intent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    Button Alarm_ON = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu1);
    Alarm_ON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int hour = 0;
            int minute = 0;
            int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            if (currentApiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {

                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getHour());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getMinute());

                hour = alarmTimePicker.getHour();
                minute = alarmTimePicker.getMinute();
            } else {
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());

                hour = alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
                minute = alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
            }


            String hour_string = String.valueOf(hour);
            String minute_string = String.valueOf(minute);


            if (hour > 12) {
                hour_string = String.valueOf(hour - 12);
            }

            if (minute < 10) {

                minute_string = "0" + String.valueOf(minute);
            }
            //setAlarmText("Alarm set to: " + hour_string + ":" + minute_string);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm set to: " + hour_string + ":" + minute_string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            my_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm on");

            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 0,
                    my_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    pendingIntent);

        }
    });
```

What we have done here is - 
1) From the main Activity .class file this AlarmReciever.class file will be called and as per the scheduled time the alarm will ring dosen't matter whether the phone's locked or not.

Got any questions then do reply here. :) and don't forget to accept the answer bu pressing the Tick mark.